# Resolute - also "morally lax"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Is the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/resolute) saying resolute also (historically) means morally lax, as some kind of autoantonym?

> resolute (adj.)
> early 15c., "dissolved, of loose structure," also
> "morally lax," from Latin *resolutus*, past participle of *resolvere*
> "untie, unfasten, loose, loosen" ...

Comment: No, it's saying that it _did_ mean that before 1500.

Comment: What do reputable modern dictionaries say about modern usage? Etymon (and etymologies in dictionaries) include earlier meanings, which may be obsolete.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My searching so far found nothing about "morally lax" so I think the quote's idea is "dissolved, of loose structure *or* moral laxity".  In fact, that looks fairly obvious now.

Comment: OED **resolute**, *adj.* **Etymology**: < classical Latin resolūtus - having a loosened texture, not cohesive, slack, limp, free from constraint, unrestrained, -- †1. Dissolved; softened. Obsolete.†2. a. Loose in texture, not compact. -- **2.b. figurative. Morally lax, dissolute. Obsolete. rare—1.** ?a1475  *After that he wente to the cite of Crotines, resolute moche in vertues and in honeste.*

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks.  So it has actually reversed its meaning.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, I couldn't see how it could be, but you're right.